# Error:Only plain objects, and a few built-ins,can be passed to Client Components from Server Components. Classes or null prototypes are not supported

Tags: next.js

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import PersonIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Person";
import LockIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Lock";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { login } from "@/lib/action";
import styles from "./loginForm.module.css";

const LoginForm = () => {
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState(login, undefined);

  return (
    <form className={styles.form} action={formAction}>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <div className={styles.inputBox}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" />
        <div className={styles.icon}>
          <PersonIcon />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.inputBox}>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />
        <div className={styles.icon}>
          <LockIcon />
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className={styles.btn}>
        Login
      </button>
      <div className={styles.error}>{state?.error}</div>
      <div className={styles.registerLink}>
        <p>
          Don't have an account ? <Link href="/register">Register</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`LoginForm`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `LoginForm`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render